# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of null

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

```
var ReportFolderListUtil = {
    confirmBox2:null,
    showConfirmation: function(reportFolderId){
        console.log(reportFolderId);

        this.confirmBox2 = Lobibox.confirm({
            delay:false,
            title : 'Confirmation',
            msg : "Please take note that reports created under this folder will also be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete this folder?",
            buttons: {
                yes: {
                    'class': 'btn btn-success',
                    closeOnClick: false
                },
                no: {
                    'class': 'btn btn-default',
                    closeOnClick: true
                }
            },
            callback: function ($this, type, ev) {
                if (type === 'yes')
                    window.location.href = "/report/remove-folder/"+reportFolderId+".html";
                    ReportFolderListUtil.hideConfirmation();
                    JobUtil.showLoading("deleteReport","deleting folder.");
                }
            }
        })
    },
    hideConfirmation: function(){
        this.confirmBox2.hide();
    }
```

I keep getting this errors on my console:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you're calling `hideConfirmation` before you call `showConfirmation`? You could add a check before you call `hide`. e.g. `if (this.confirmBox2) this.confirmBox2.hide();`

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand your code, the issue is that you are calling `ReportFolderListUtil.hideConfirmation` method before `ReportFolderListUtil.showConfirmation` method, so `ReportFolderListUtil.confirmBox2` is not re-initialized with `this.confirmBox2 = Lobibox.confirm` inside `showConfirmation` method body, it is `null` per `ReportFolderListUtil` variable declaring.

Depending on your needs you may

a) protect `hideConfirmation` in a way like

```
hideConfirmation: function() {
    this.confirmBox2 && this.confirmBox2.hide();
}
```

b) or define hide-method stub

```
var ReportFolderListUtil = {
  confirmBox2: { 
    hide: function () { }
  },
```

c) or review the order of methods invocation, for not to call hide before show...

Answer (score 0):

confirmBox2 isn't going to have a value until you execute "showConfirmation" in this context. also you are missing a curly bracket on the "if" in your callback.

its important to keep the state of your objects in mind when executing functions. 
to prevent a fatal error i would suggest more null checks 
`if( confirmbox2 ) { //execute request }`